# prevent mac from renaming downloads' extensions

Tags: mac, google-chrome, file, macos

Sometimes I download something, and OS X (or Chrome, not sure) decides that the file extension must be changed.

Is it possible to completely disable this feature? How?

I guess this is a Google Chrome issue, but triggered in OS X because it hides file extensions by default? I'm not sure how it works and what triggers this, but I'd just like to have the downloaded file's name not to be messed with.

You're offered the option of which extension to use, but sometimes, even if you choose the right extension, it still screws up the filename.

[image: Screenshot - sometimes, even if you choose the right extension, it still screws up the filename]

Comment: This is not a function of OS X that I am aware of. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I added a screenshot that illustrates the problem.

Comment: And that little icon on the left of the dialog means ...

Comment: I guess it's a chrome feature, instead of os x's?

Comment: Chrome is most likely reading the headers accompanying the file download and making assumptions based on that. Only thing I can think of. This is not an OS X feature.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Chrome menu and select preferences. Scroll to the bottom of the preference window and click on Advanced. This lets you scroll down to a 2nd page off options that you can use or turn off. Two of the first options refer to using a Prediction service for loading web pages. You can try turning one or both of these off to get rid of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

OS X does not change extension of your downloaded file. Do you have any example (i.e., link) where Chrome does this?

Comment: check the screenshot

Comment: I used http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=lts it doesn't happen. File is saved as .iso

Comment: try downloading the torrent, e.g., http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.3-server-amd64.iso.torrent

this only happens to certain file types

Comment: It recent versions of macOS it may "help" you by changing eg .img to .dmg if you don't have the Finder setting to "Show all file extensions" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly in my opinion Apple went a little too far in "helping the user" with this. When I try to save a .img file from a website, if I have "Show all file extensions" turned off in Finder> Preferences> Advanced, then it automatically renames the file with a .dmg extension, which is NOT the same thing and most applications that work with .img files don't understand or allow selecting a .dmg file in their file browser.

Luckily the fix is simply to check the box for "Show all file extensions" and then just make sure you don't remove an existing extension when downloading from a website. If a download doesn't have or offer an extension, you can usually add .pdf as the Preview application can handle almost every type of text/image/pdf/video out there, and if it can't, then you probably need to use a command line tool like `file` to guess at the type of file it REALLY is. `file --help` in Terminal will get you started.

One thing to note is that file extensions are primarily for humans, computers can use "magic" file headers or a mime type examination to figure out what program can handle a file, but humans think we know best, which is why we want to manage or override "file handlers", but often things "just work" if we don't go messing with them too much.